# How we call a function in swift3.0

Tags: ios8, swift3, apple-maps

```
func directionsFromCurrentLocation(to:CLLocationCoordinate2D,directionCompletionHandler:DirectionsCompletionHandler){
```

This code is used in apple map for finding between two destination.
and, i am using this code.

```
mapManager.directionsFromCurrentLocation(to: destination!) { (route, directionInformation, boundingRegion, error) -> () in
```

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0):

If you're bothered by the trailing closure ( the `{ }` delimited chunk of code at the end of your function call) please read the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102).

In short (taken from the link above):

> If you need to pass a closure expression to a function as the
>   function’s final argument and the closure expression is long, it can
>   be useful to write it as a trailing closure instead. A trailing
>   closure is written after the function call’s parentheses, even though
>   it is still an argument to the function. When you use the trailing
>   closure syntax, you don’t write the argument label for the closure as
>   part of the function call.

```
func someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(closure: () -> Void) {
    // function body goes here
}

// Here's how you call this function without using a trailing closure:
someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(closure: {
    // closure's body goes here
})

// Here's how you call this function with a trailing closure instead:
someFunctionThatTakesAClosure() {
    // trailing closure's body goes here
}
```